# Trying to print out the line numbers of a file, using an int variable

Tags: c++, printing, numbers, line

I was working on a cs project in c++, we had to open a file read the words and print them out in alphabetical order and next to the word print what line it was found on.  I used recursive functions to do this but for some reason my counter which i was using to mark the line numbers will not update.  I tried using a pointer for it but still nothing. I might have done the pointer wrong but i made the int var global so that should have handled it, but still nothing.  I already turned in the assignment, but I want to know why the counter never worked.  There are a few hacks in this code, like convert string to c_str(), but that was just to try and get my OR arguments to work, please ignore them.
Any advice?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm> //This is to do a comparison of ASCII characters.
#include<cctype>    //This is to convert capital letters to lowercase.
#include<string>    //This is to work with strings
#include<fstream>   //This is to work with getline().
#include<cstring>


using namespace std;
// Node
 struct node {
    int line;
    string word;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};
// MakeNode Function creates nodes
node* makeNode(string word, int line) {
    node* newNode = new node();
    newNode->word = word;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
    delete newNode;
}
// Function to insert new nodes into the tree.
node* Insert(node* root,string word, int line) {
    if(root == NULL) { // empty tree
        root = makeNode(word, line);
    }
    // If word is less then root-word
    else if(word <= root->word) {
        root->left = Insert(root->left,word, line);
        root->line = line;
    }
    // If word is greater then root-word
    else {
        root->right = Insert(root->right,word, line);
        root->line = line;
     }
    return root;
}
// Print function to print tree
void printTree(node* root)
{
     if (root == NULL){// If tree doesn't exist

      return;
     }
     else{

    printTree(root->left);
    cout<<root->word<<"\t"<<root->line<<endl;
    printTree(root->right);
    }
}






int main() {

int lineNum = 1; // Set line equal to one.
// cout<<lineNum<<endl;
node* root = NULL;  // Creating an empty tree
string word;        // Var to hold word

ifstream quote ("quote.txt"); // Opens the text file

getline(quote,word,' '); // Gets the words from the text file.

root = Insert(root, word, lineNum);
while(!quote.eof() || word != "#"){// While loop to read all words from text      file.
     int * line = lineNum;
        *line++;
    cout<<"This is the word right now: "<<word<<endl;
    char *newLine  = new char[word.length()+1];
    strcpy(newLine, word.c_str());

    cout<<"This is the newLine[0] value right now: "<<newLine[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"This is lineNum after the if"<<*line<<endl;

    if(newLine[0] == '\n'){// Increments line by keeping track of \n line char.


        cout<<"This is lineNum after the if"<<*line<<endl;
    }
    unsigned wordSize = word.size();
    if(wordSize > 10){// Shortens word if it is longer then ten chars.
        word.resize(10);
    }
    root = Insert(root, word, *line);
        quote>>word;

        delete[] newLine;





}// End of While

quote.close();


printTree(root);
}
```

/***********************************************************************
    this is the content of the quote file:

```
civilization of science
science is knowledge
knowledge is our destiny
#// this hash is to mark the end of the paragraph.



/**************************************************************************
This is a scaled down version of what the problem is, as you can see the 
*ptr variable is not updating.*/

int main()
{

int num = 1;
int *ptr = &num;

cout<<*ptr<<endl;

int key = 0;
while(key < 5){

    cout<<"This is *prt: "<<*ptr<<endl;
    cout<<"This is key: "<<key<<endl;
    key++;
    *ptr++;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 0):

While Nathan Oliver is correct in his assessment you probably might also want to take a look at this:

```
int * line = lineNum;
```

I'm not sure why you're using a pointer but given the rest of your code I'm not sure A) it is doing what you think it is doing and B) why it isn't crashing.  Were I a gambling man I'd wager this is your error right here.

Comment: There is no reason why `int * line = lineNum;` should crash, but the next line  `*line++;` is causing UB. I mean you can assign any value you like to a pointer as long as you dont try to dereference it

Comment: I thought the pointer would dereferene before being incremented.

Comment: Hey guys ok, i wrote a scaled down version of what's going wrong.

Comment: int main()
{

int num = 1;
int *ptr = &num;

    cout<<*ptr<<endl;

    int key = 0;
    while(key < 5){

        cout<<"This is *prt: "<<*ptr<<endl;
        cout<<"This is key: "<<key<<endl;
        key++;
        *ptr++;
    }

    return 0;
}

Comment: @soulsabr, mainly because they want us to use pointers whenever we can for practice and second, I had suspected that maybe my issue was a scoping problem that for some reason the int variable couldn't be accessed inside the while loop, so i though a pointer could overcome this.

Comment: @RiceMan I see.  Don't be afraid to practice, experiment, and especially don't be afraid to fail.  You learn best by screwing up and then fixing it.  Get in there, get your hands dirty, and if you really REALLY don't understand something and can't figure it out then come poke us for some help.  Scope is super important in any language.  Pointers are if the language supports them.  You'll thank yourself later for getting this down now.